# Improving performance of a [mysql query with 'in clause']

Tags: mysql, performance, explain

I have a query that retrieves data from two tables.

`table1` has an int field, `table1_id` which is the primary key.

`table2` has two fields; `table1_id`, an int field (which references `table1.table1_id`) and `field1`, a bit field.

There are three indexes on `table2`: `table1_id`, `field1` and `table1_id_field1` (the indexes are on the fields indicated by the names).

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *  FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.table1_id = t1.table1_id 
WHERE t2.table1_id IN 
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

The plan for this query (obtained by using `EXPLAIN`) is this:

```
id   select_type   table   type    possible_keys                     key              key_len  ref               rows   Extra
1    SIMPLE        t2      range   table1_id,field1,table1_id_field1 table1_id_field1 8        NULL              29858  Using where
1    SIMPLE        t1      eq_ref  PRIMARY                           PRIMARY          8        db1.t2.table1_id  1
```

Now when I add an additional where clause to the query, like so:

```
SELECT *  FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.table1_id = t1.table1_id 
WHERE t2.table1_id IN 
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) 
**AND field1 = 0**
```

The query is no longer using as efficient an index as before; here is the query plan:

```
id   select_type   table   type     possible_keys                     key      key_len  ref                rows   Extra
1    SIMPLE        t2      ref      table1_id,field1,table1_id_field1 field1   2        const              98913  Using where
1    SIMPLE        t1      eq_ref   PRIMARY                           PRIMARY  8        db1.t2.table1_id   1
```

It now searches more rows (98913) than before (29858), and it is no longer using the index it was using before in the original query (it is using `field1` instead of `table1_id_field1`.

My questions are:

1. Is there a reason that the second query with the additional clause is not using the index it was using in the first query?
2. Is there any way I can make mysql choose a more efficient index, other than using `FORCE INDEX`? Maybe I need to add another index?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that having too many redundant indexes confuses optimizer, so it chooses the wrong one.

It seems to me that it's enough to have just one index on table2, `table1_id_field1` because `table1_id` is a leading column, so this index can be used for enforcing FK; thus, no need for index on `table1_id`. Index on `field1` cannot be selective (since it's on bit field) to be efficient.

Comment: I'll try eliminating the other indexes and seeing what happens.